# CreateThread. Не работает второй поток в Win.

Tags: winapi, многопоточность, c++, visual-c++

В общем, код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int global = 0;

int main() {
    int x, count;
    char seq[100];
    char seqNew[100];
    cin>>seq;
    strcpy(seqNew, seq);
    count = strlen(seq);
    for(int i=count-1; i>0; i--){
        if(seq[i]==seq[i-1])
            seqNew[i] = '0';
        else
            seqNew[i] = '1';
    }
    seqNew[0] = '1';
    cout<<"\n"<<seqNew<<"\n";
    cout<<global;

    cin>>x;
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI MyThread(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    BOOL *Active;
    Active = (BOOL*)lpParameter;
    *Active = TRUE;

    while(global<10){
        global++;
    }

    *Active = FALSE;
    ExitThread(0);
}

void InitThread()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD  ThreadId;
    BOOL   Active;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0,
                           (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyThread,
                           (void*)&Active, 0, &ThreadId);

    while(Active == TRUE);

    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

Почему же не выполняется второй поток (`MyThread`)? В переменную global должно попасть значение 10.
Правильно ли я запускаю поток? 
И какая область видимости у второго потока?

*Заранее благодарю!* 
З.Ы. Нормальную документацию с примером не могу найти.

Comment: @avp спасибо) А какая область видимости этого потока?

Comment: Не понимаю термин "область видимости потока". 

У Вас первая вызванная в новом потоке функция это MyThread. Что она видит, то и может читать/менять в этом (и любом другом) потоке. На самом деле один поток всегда уже есть (main в нем запущена).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нашел, где Вы его запускаете. IMHO в main не вызова InitThread()

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите работающий пример: [Creating Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx).

Ваш код не должен работать:

1. Переменная Active размещается на стэке функции и после выхода из нее становится неопределенной.
2. Функция InitThread не запускается из функции main, следовательно второй поток не стартует.

Comment: Не все ок. avp ответил мне. А прототип функции void InitThread(); я описал, но здесь не написал))

Answer (score 0):

И использовать конструкции вида `while(Active == TRUE);`... Даже не знаю как назвать. Зачем тогда нужен `WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);` который ожидает завершения потока? А после него уже `CloseHandle(hThread);`.